# If (array variable) syntax valid in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, if-statement

I've been wondering about this syntax I picked up when attempting to accomplish some functionality using jQuery/javascript and was wondering if this is actually valid syntax or not. It seems to work, but it could be that javascript is just defaulting for true in the if-clause. I assumed it just validates whether or not the array has entries/is a valid array. Can anyone explain to me if the following is valid/invalid and if it is valid, what is it checking exactly?

```
var arrVariable = new Array();

... push things to array, etc.

if(arrVariable)    {
     ... doing stuff with array.    
}
```

Comment: Objects are always truthy.

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by *valid* array? If you are looking for elements in the array I would use `arrVariable.length`.

Comment: arrays are objects too :) and empty arrays...

Comment: try yo use `Array.isArray(arrVar) && arrVar.length`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(arrVariable) {

}
```

This if statement evaluates if `arrVariable` is *truthy* or *falsy*.

The following values are always falsy:

- `false`
- `0`
- `""`
- `null`
- `undefined`
- `NaN`

All other values are truthy ([*source*](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)).

> I assumed it just validates whether or not the array has entries/is a valid array.

This is not true. An empty array is an object and is therefore truthy. You can test this quite easily:

```
var arr = [];
if (arr) {
    console.log('arr is empty, but truthy, so this statement executes');
}
```

Comment: Also note that "false" is truthy, while false is not.

Comment: Oh wow, I never knew there was such a thing as "truthy" or "falsy" in javascript. Thanks for the answer and explanation!

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = ["one", "two"];
```

Check if the array has entries in it:

```
if (arr.length) {
    //There is at least one entry in the array
}
```

To check if it's an array:

```
if (arr instanceof Array) {
    //It's an array
}
```